# Updating subtables adds records rather than amending existing records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have these two models:

```
public class Balance1 : IAnalyticsSection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DataFileId { get; set; }

    public string Side { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageHSway { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageSSpeed { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageLHSway { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageRHSway { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentAverageInLSphere { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentAverageInRSphere { get; set; }
    public decimal AverageTotalSway { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Balance1Part> Parts { get; set; } = new List<Balance1Part>();
    public virtual DataFile DataFile { get; set; }
}


public class Balance1Part
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Balance1Id { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
    public decimal ConvexHullArea { get; set; }
    public decimal HSway { get; set; }
    public decimal SSpeeds { get; set; }
    public decimal LHSway { get; set; }
    public decimal RHSway { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentInLSphere { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentInRSphere { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSway { get; set; }
        
    public virtual Balance1 Balance1 { get; set; }
}
```

In my context I have `public DbSet<Balance1> Balance1 { get; set; }` but nothing for `Balance1Part`. There will only ever be 5 `Balance1Part` records for each `Balance1`. When I enter a new record into `Balance1`, it successfully creates with each of the 5 parts. If I try to update `Balance1` it succeeds but 5 additional part records are created. These are duplicates of the existing records.

This is is the code that enters/updates my `Balance1` and `Balance1Parts`:

```
var innerBalance1File = await innerContext.Balance1.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.DataFileId == dataFile.Id);
                            
Balance1Class balance1Class = new Balance1Class();

if (innerBalance1File == null)
{
    innerBalance1File = new Balance1();
    innerBalance1File.DataFileId = dataFile.Id;
    innerBalance1File = balance1Class.Balance1Data(innerBalance1File, values);

    await innerContext.AddAsync(innerBalance1File);
}
else
{
    innerBalance1File = balance1Class.Balance1Data(innerBalance1File, values);
    innerContext.Entry(innerBalance1File).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

await innerContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is my `Balance1Calss`:

```
public class Balance1Class
{
    // create a method that has dataFile and values passed to it, populates the dataFile keys with appropriate values and returns datafile
    public Balance1 Balance1Data(Balance1 balance1, Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        //Balance1 balance1 = new Balance1();
        //Balance1Part balance1Part = new Balance1Part();

        if ((values["DataType"]).Equals("Balance1R"))
        {
            balance1.Side = "R";
        }
        else
        {
            balance1.Side = "L";
        }

        balance1.AverageHSway = decimal.Parse(values["AverageHSway"].ToString());
        balance1.AverageLHSway = decimal.Parse(values["AverageLHSway"].ToString());
        balance1.AverageRHSway = decimal.Parse(values["AverageRHSway"].ToString());
        balance1.AverageSSpeed = decimal.Parse(values["AverageSSpeed"].ToString());
        balance1.AverageTotalSway = decimal.Parse(values["AverageTotalSway"].ToString());
        balance1.PercentAverageInLSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%AverageInLSphere"].ToString());
        balance1.PercentAverageInRSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%AverageInRSphere"].ToString());

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Balance1Part balance1Part = new Balance1Part
            {
                HSway = decimal.Parse(values["HSway" + i].ToString()),
                SSpeeds = decimal.Parse(values["SSpeeds" + i].ToString()),
                LHSway = decimal.Parse(values["LHSway" + i].ToString()),
                RHSway = decimal.Parse(values["RHSway" + i].ToString()),
                PercentInLSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InLSphere" + i].ToString()),
                PercentInRSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InRSphere" + i].ToString()),
                TotalSway = decimal.Parse(values["TotalSway" + i].ToString()),
                ConvexHullArea = decimal.Parse(values["ConvexHullArea" + i].ToString()),
                Order = i,
            };
            balance1.Parts.Add(balance1Part);
        }

        return balance1;
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong with this?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer bbelow I updated my `for` to this:

```
var balance1Parts = balance1.Parts;  // Gets actual balance parts: returns a list

if (balance1Parts.Count == 0 || balance1Parts == null)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Balance1Part balance1Part = new Balance1Part
        {
            HSway = decimal.Parse(values["HSway" + i].ToString()),
            SSpeeds = decimal.Parse(values["SSpeeds" + i].ToString()),
            LHSway = decimal.Parse(values["LHSway" + i].ToString()),
            RHSway = decimal.Parse(values["RHSway" + i].ToString()),
            PercentInLSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InLSphere" + i].ToString()),
            PercentInRSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InRSphere" + i].ToString()),
            TotalSway = decimal.Parse(values["TotalSway" + i].ToString()),
            ConvexHullArea = decimal.Parse(values["ConvexHullArea" + i].ToString()),
            Order = i,
        };
        balance1.Parts.Add(balance1Part);
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (var balance1Part in balance1Parts)
    {
        balance1Part.HSway = decimal.Parse(values["HSway" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.SSpeeds = decimal.Parse(values["SSpeeds" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.LHSway = decimal.Parse(values["LHSway" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.RHSway = decimal.Parse(values["RHSway" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.PercentInLeftSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InLSphere" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.PercentInRSphere = decimal.Parse(values["%InRSphere" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.TotalSway = decimal.Parse(values["TotalSway" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.ConvexHullArea = decimal.Parse(values["ConvexHullArea" + balance1Part.Order].ToString());
        balance1Part.Order = int.Parse(values["Order"].ToString());
        balance1.Parts.Add(balance1Part);
    }
}
```

It still only adds new parts rather than updating existing parts. I think the context isn't getting updated correctly for the parts as the second time I run this I would expect `innerBalance1File` to contain the parts but when I logged this out it was not there. Can anybody please advise what's wrong?

Should I add `innerContext.Balance1.Update(innerBalance1File);` between these lines?

```
innerBalance1File = balance1Class.Balance1Data(innerBalance1File, values);
innerContext.Entry(innerBalance1File).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It doesn't seem like something that should be required.

**UPDATE**

I added `innerContext.Balance1.Update(innerBalance1File);` and removed `innerContext.Entry(innerBalance1File).State = EntityState.Modified;` but got the same result. Do I need to use `Attach` here? I'm thinking something like `innerContext.Attach(innerBalance1File.Parts);` before `innerContext.Balance1.Update(innerBalance1File);`.

Answer (score 0):

The following line executes what you said: create 5 new subitems `Balance1Part` and later add them.

```
Balance1Part balance1Part = new Balance1Part
```

If you want to update them instead, then you should replace this `for` block code by something like:

```
var balance1Parts = balance1.Parts;  // Gets actual balance parts: returns a list

if (balance1Parts == null)
{
    // Here the balance parts don't exist yet, so you can keep current code to create them
}
else
{
    // Here the balance parts are already set. 
    // So loop on every balance part and update it.
    // BUT! You'll have to find/set a unique identifier to know which one to update with which data ;)
    foreach (var balancePart in balance1Parts)
    {
        balancePart.HSway = decimal.Parse(values["HSway" + i].ToString());
        balancePart.SSpeeds = decimal.Parse(values["SSpeeds" + i].ToString());
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

Don't forget to save your changes in ths DB context and you'll should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @paradise. For `if (balance1Parts == null)`, is that correct that it could be `null` or is it likely to just be empty? Perhaps this query is relevant to the EF version. I'm using `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.6`.

Comment: Also, changes have been saved in db context as per `await innerContext.SaveChangesAsync()` in the example above. Is anything else required?